# Ajax response not showing in JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, echo

I have an AJAX script like this

```
function savetoDB(inp) {
    var userID = (FB.getAuthResponse() || {}).userID;

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: 'GET',
        data:{ 'input': JSON.stringify(inp) },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        success: function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the php returns (echo's) some string , but I am unable to see it in alert.
I used the inspect element and Inside inspect element I can see the Response, and also the status is 200, what could be the reason that it is not showing the response in alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a JSON object, so it won't show in alert, which only displays strings.  Convert it to a string first:

```
success: function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
}
```

Comment: I am just echoing some stuff, I am not returning JSON, how can you say that?

Comment: @Badddy Your ajax call is interpreting it as JSON. regardless if you format the output or not.

Comment: @Badddy You removed the contentType from the ajax request and changed the dataType from json to html?

Comment: @Mic1780 no I didn't since I am sending JSON data from here

Comment: @Badddy, dataType: 'json' means you're expecting JSON back.

Comment: what does console.log(msg) show?  just some plain text, or an object of some sort?

Comment: from the network panel of chrome dev tools, would you please copy the entire response into the question?

Comment: @manishie my script was expecting JSON true, I used echo json_encode and it worked Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace "URL" with the actual url of file you're extracting data from otherwise you'll get an empty response as is the case.